# Gulp error with gulp-compass : You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory

Tags: compass-sass, gulp

I try to run a gulp task to compile my sass project but since I create subfolder app/assets/ and put my sources files into it, I have a issue. Before when sass and css folder was in the same directory than my gulpfile it was running perfectly. And if I run a compass watch command on my base directory I have no issue, this is only with gulp-compass.

The output :

```
Devnco: /Users/Devnco/Web/maquette ->gulp sass
[gulp] Using gulpfile ~/Web/maquette/gulpfile.js
[gulp] Starting 'sass'...
[gulp] Finished 'sass' after 6.12 ms
[gulp] You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory.
[gulp] Plumber found unhandled error: [gulp] Error in plugin 'gulp-compass': Compass failed
[gulp] You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory.
[gulp] Plumber found unhandled error: [gulp] Error in plugin 'gulp-compass': Compass failed
[gulp] You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory.
[gulp] Plumber found unhandled error: [gulp] Error in plugin 'gulp-compass': Compass failed
```

My gulpfile.js :

```
var paths = {
    css: './app/assets/css',
    sass: './app/assets/sass/*.scss',
    js: './app/assets/js',
    images: './app/assets/images'
}

gulp.task('sass',function(){

    gulp.src(paths.sass)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(compass({
            css: paths.css,
            sass: paths.sass
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css))
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css));
});
```

My working directory :

```
gulpfile.js
app/
    assets/
        fonts/
        images/
        sass/
        css/
    pages/
        etc…
```

And my package.json with the versions that I use (lastest)

```
"devDependencies": {
  "gulp": "^3.6.2",
  "gulp-compass": "^1.1.9",
  "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
  "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.4",
  "gulp-plumber": "^0.6.2",
  "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0"
}
```

I made some searches but not still not found where is the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this to compile my compass file and it works fine, it comes right from the gulp-compass docs

if you are not using config.rb

```
var compass = require('gulp-compass'),
  path = require('path');

gulp.task('compass', function() {
  gulp.src('./src/*.scss')
  .pipe(compass({
    project: path.join(__dirname, 'assets'),
    css: 'css',
    sass: 'sass'
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/temp'));
});
```

if you are using config.rb

var compass = require('gulp-compass');

```
gulp.task('compass', function() {
  gulp.src('./src/*.scss')
  .pipe(compass({
    config_file: './config.rb',
    css: 'stylesheets',
    sass: 'sass'
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/temp'));
});
```

Comment: Do you leave __dirname exactly as it is?  Or is that updated with your own directory name?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem tonight as well. I fixed it by changing my config.rb path. Try

```
.pipe(compass({
  config_file: './config.rb',
  css: paths.css,
  sass: paths.sass
}))
```

If you don't have / want to use a config.rb I believe you have to set the project root like in the "Load config without config.rb" section of https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-compass

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue as well, I found that the project path needs to point to the folder that contains the folder with the css, scss. For instance:

```
app /
  - src /
      - css /
      - sass /
```

given the above structure, your config should look like:

```
project: "app/src",
css: "css",
sass: "sass"
```

I got the error when my project path was one level higher, making my css property look like: `"src/css"`